# Parse Out ES _source

Tags: express, elasticsearch

I've created my first GET API call that does a fuzzy search against an Elastic Search index and so far everything works well (w00t w00t). I'm stuck on one piece though; I'd like to parse out some of the information returned from ElasticSearch, specifically in the `_source` section. I've done some recon and discovered that you can use a mapping function to do this, but I can't get the results to display on the page or console. So the question is, let's say I just wanted to pull out the `name` field from `_source` is that possible and is there a preferred method to do it?

```
router.get('/suggest/:search', function(req, res, next) {

const searchTerm = req.params.search;

client.search({
    index: 'product_pipeline_import',
    type: 'jdbc-demo',
    body: {
        suggest: {
            productSuggest: {
                prefix: searchTerm,
                completion: {
                    field: 'name',
                    fuzzy: {
                        fuzziness: 2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).then(function(resp) {
    var hits = resp.hits.hits.map(function(hit){
        console.log(hit._source)
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.trace(err.message);
});
```

})

What I'm trying to parse from:

```
  {
              "text": "Philips - Brilliance 27\" IPS LED HD Monitor - Text",
              "_index": "test-index",
              "_type": "products",
              "_id": "Philips - Brilliance 27\" IPS LED HD Monitor - Textured Black",
              "_score": 5,
              "_source": {
                "name": "Philips - Brilliance 27\" IPS LED HD Monitor - Textured Black",
                "@version": "1",
                "model": "272P4APJKEB",
                "@timestamp": "2017-11-19T20:56:11.537Z",
                "type": "products",
                "manufacturer": "Philips"
              }
```

Comment: What you get back is a JSON object, so you can access the name field using `hit._source.name`

Comment: Thanks @Val , I did see that yesterday on another post, since the data is serialized already you don't need to do anything to it. I just can't get the results to dump to the browser with `res.send` or `console.log` - the request just hangs